# How do I persist the selected value of dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdownlist with 3 items shown below:

```
     <asp:ListItem Text="none" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Not Started</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

The database field name is `status`.

By default, when a request is inserted into the database for the first time, value of Not Started is inserted into the database.

When a user loads the gridview in Edit mode, we would like to see the above dropdownlist list with `Not Started` pre-populated with the value of `Not Started`.

If the user updates that row and changes the dropdownlist value from `Not Started` to say `Pending`, next time a user loads the same gridview, we would like to see the value of `Pending` as the selected value.

In other words, we would like to see the last inserted value be the selected value when the gridview is loaded in edit mode.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

The below is populate from the db.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status">
                   <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlstatus" CssClass="dropdown" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What have you done till now? Any code snippet?

Comment: I know people who ask that question - what have you done?

They often have nothing to offer.

But I have updated my code above with what I have done so far.

How do I ensure that when one of the 3 values of db field Status is  updated, that it becomes the first selected value in the dropdownlist without losing the other 2 values.

Thanks really @Daredev

Comment: Well, I'll try to change that notion for you. Thanks for posting code snippet. What I see is that you are able to bind the value of status from DB to `lblstatus` label, but you haven't bounded the value of status from DB to `ddlstatus` anywhere. Please check & I'm checking in the meantime too.

Comment: Thank you @Daredev.

This is actually the FIRST time, this has happened; not just with my post with several other posts where someone asks that question just to be be funny.

You are right that ddlstatus is not bound to db and that's the error I am getting. My biggest issue is how to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first list item, or place it last, making the "Not Started" item first, then it should be the item selected when the control is first placed on the form

Comment: unless I misunderstand you, that's not what I am looking for.

As stated in my original post, if I select `Pending` and save it to the database, next time I load that gridview, I want to see `Pending` as the selected item on the dropdownlist.

Anytime an update is made, whatever item is selected from the dropdownlist and inserted into the db, becomes the first item selected when gridview is loaded in summary or edit mode.

I hope this clarifies what we need.

Comment: Sorry, you should update the Drop down list to include the fields DataValueField="status" DataTextField="status", this should link the record with the control